# Solving NxN puzzle In 2-dimensional array

Tags: java, algorithm

I am solving a NxN puzzle in Java 2D array (`int state[][]`) and I am stuck.

I am using the Manhattan distance heuristic. The problem I have now is how to code the successors of a node. I have seen numerous examples on the net how a node's successors (neighbours) are generated but they are all in 1 dimensional array. I can't find any tutorial that teaches generating the successors of a node in 2D arrays.

How can I code to generate the successors of a node? A node can move to the empty space to the LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN or UP. The size of the board is NxN.

It is my first time using 2D arrays to program game like these puzzles.

Comment: @Eddy Freeman: next time remember to tag your homework questions.

Comment: It is not homework.  For the fact that it is my first time doesn't mean it is homework. You don't add homework tag to it. If it is homework, i would have tagged it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the code you have defines

```
UP as ( i + width * (j-1))
DOWN as ( i + width * (j+1))
LEFT as ( i - 1 + width * j)
RIGHT as (i + 1 + width *j)
```

You need to define these as (i, j-1), (i, j+1), (i-1, j), (i+1, j) respectively.

Edit:

In a 1D array, you need to flatten the element index. If the element is at column i, row j, flat address would be ( j*width [meaning skip j rows] + i [meaning skip i items in this row]). If you have a 2D array then you can simple use array[i][j] instead of a flat address.

Comment: I appreciate your answer but please can you help me to understand it very well. It is my first time of using 2D arrays to program a game like this so every thing looks new to me. So please can you edit your answer and give me some explanation to understand what you mean by define these as (i-1, j), (i+1, j),etc...  thanks for your reply

Comment: thanks. So how does the flat array you described is related to the 2D arrays?

Comment: so what I'm suggesting is to find in the original code, each value that is used as an index to the 1D array, figure out if it refers to up/down/left/right/current, and convert them into 2D indices.