# How Can I determine The Direction To Move

Tags: java, algorithm

I am solving an NxN puzzle in java 2D array. I can move to the empty tile in say four directions : LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN or UP.  My question is if i get the indices(row en column values) of the empty tiles(node), how can i know if i must move LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN or UP to generate its successor(neighbour) nodes.

For instance if it is a 1Dimensional array of 9 elements then i can do something like: `index` is the index of the empty tile

```
if(index == 0){
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(0,1,arrayPosition),curNode));
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(0,3,arrayPosition),curNode));
        }
        else if(index == 1){
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(0,1,arrayPosition),curNode));
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(1, 4, arrayPosition),curNode));
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(1, 2, arrayPosition),curNode));
        }

        ....

         if(index == 8){
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(8, 7, arrayPosition),curNode));
            tempSuccessorNodes.add(new Node(swap(8, 5, arrayPosition),curNode));
        }
```

to generate the successors of the current node. But here am dealing with NxN(which 3x3 is an instance). How do i know if i must move LEFT, RIGHT, DOWN or UP after knowing the indices of the empty cell/tile/node?

I have a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218292/solving-nxn-puzzle-in-2-dimensional-array) here i posted earlier which relates to the same task am handling

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to take two things into account, to determine in which direction you can move:

1. Whether you have already visited one of the neighboring tiles (otherwise, you risk entering an infinite loop). For that, each time you want to visit a tile you must check first if that tile has already been visited; if not add it to a set and visit it, otherwise ignore it. Notice that checking is easy, simply ask if the tile is already in the set.
2. For determining the neighbors of each tile, you must check four possible edge cases, in all other cases it's safe to visit the tiles:

   - if the tile is in the first row, don't go visiting the previous row
   - if the tile is in the last row, don't go visiting the next row
   - if the tile is in the first column, don't go visiting the previous column
   - if the tile is in the last column, don't go visiting the next column

Answer (score 0):

It is simples yo consider that you do not move the tales, but rather the space. Given the coordinates of the empty tile it can move in all directions unless it is on one of the borders, that will limit the movement.

Comment: thanks for your reply. So if i get you right, it means that i must call the up(), down(), left() en right() functions at the same time?

Comment: @EddyFreeman in general you do not know which is the right move, that is why it is a *search*, what I meant is that the empty tile can move in all the directions where it would not go off the board. That determines the search tree, and then you have to define your algorithm to search (potentially using some heuristic to drive the search)

Comment: thanks again. am using the manhattan heurestic(f = g + h) , g is the cost from start node to the current node, h is the cost from the current node to the target node. Can you give me a little explanation what to do to drive the search. it is my first time doing this so i need some specific explanation to continue. At the moment i have the four functions(up(), down(), left() en right()) so what must i do next to use the heureustic to determine the next move?